# SAP Web IDE Personal edition, problem with Git

Tags: git, sapui5

Attempting to connect to a remote git repository and push a local project over there. While everything seems alright when using a command prompt and Git commands inside the project folder, when I try to push using the Web IDE user interface, I get the authorization error below:

[image: Push failure]

Personal Web IDE version: 1.53.1,
SAPUI5 version: 1.44.12

Does it ring any bells?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you maintained your email id in the git settings of Web IDE? Are you part of the project you are trying push into, with the same email address?

Comment: @Breakpoint: Yes, have done that. I have assigned my e-mail address (using it to login to the Git repository) both to Email Address and User Name fields. I got prompted actually at some point with an authentication window and provided the correct credentials but didn't work either.

Comment: According to [the troubleshooting guide](https://help.sap.com/viewer/825270ffffe74d9f988a0f0066ad59f0/Cloud/en-US/bd0cb7ed7e2149b6b5170205cbde0de7.html) for 'Not Authorized', you may have either entered the wrong password or the wrong password may have been cached, so clear your passwords and try.

Comment: @Breakpoint: Clear the passwords from which cache? When I use Git from command line, everything works fine and at the same time I'm logged in into the Git repository using my browser. Issue occurs when I try to do it from within Personal SAP Web IDE, (which I have the impression that has embedded its own version of git). Is there any cache cleanup functionality in there? Tried but didn't find any options.

Comment: Clear the passwords from the browser itself.